# How does one enable lintr with Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, lintr

As the title says...

I've installed the [R extension for VSC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r). Every time I save an `.R` file in VSC, I get a popup that says `lintr` is not installed (it most certainly is; I've been using it). If click the install button the terminal confirms that `lintr` has been downloaded and installed, but after editing and saving the `.R` the same popup happens again.

[image: lintr fails even after install]

I've reinstalled `lintr` from VSC, from RStudio, and from R on `cmd` multiple times, and I've restarted VSC and my computer since doing so. The only other thing I can think of is that I need to change something with my user settings. I set `r.lintr.executable` explicitly, even though documentation says it will default to `r.term.windows` (in my case).

```
{
    "editor.rulers": [80,120],
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/R.exe",
    "r.lintr.executable": "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/R.exe"
}
```

If anybody has ideas on how to make this work, I'd be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Adam, do you recognize you're displaying your name in full?

Comment: Yeah. Not really concerned by it. Good lookin' out though.

Comment: BTW, I've tried myself lintr with VS Code - didn't work for me as well

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a bug in the extension. This feature is being temporarily removed. [enter link description here](https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R/issues/41)